# Auto complete as you type ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**My problem:**

I've an application up and running implemented with Asp.Net MVC, connected to a remote server which uses MySQL.

I have retrieved the drop down list from the remote server and it is running dynamic. I would like to edit the drop down box and make it searchable/filterable or autocomplete. I've been doing some research how to achieve this. Looks like we can do it by following:

1. JQuery autocomplete plugin
2. Chosen plug in
3. Write your own JQuery and etc.

The issue is that, most people are using SQL Server and it is very straight forward to import that model directly using ADO.NET and write JQuery to make the drop down autocomplete. But, in my case. I have the connection with a remote MySQL server. As you all know, I cannot or at least I don't know how to connect ODBC Data Source to Visual Studio.

I saw few posts talking about autocomplete using PHP, JQuery and MYSQL. But not with ASP.NET. If you have any suggestion or solution, please let me know. Thank you!

Following is my code for view and controller to get drop down box using ODBC. I did try some JQuery from other posts, but it didn't turn out well. I don't have anything more to show you.

**Controller**

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (OdbcConnection connfb = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Fishbowl"))
        {
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select abc from xyz", connfb))
            {
                connfb.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                //da.Fill(dt);
                da.Fill(ds);

                List<AddInventoryModel> refNumList = new List<AddInventoryModel>();
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    AddInventoryModel robj = new AddInventoryModel();
                    robj.referenceNumber = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["num"].ToString();
                    refNumList.Add(robj);
                }
                Adi.refNumDD = refNumList;
            }
            connfb.Close();
```

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.referenceNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-100" })
        <div class="col-md-20">
            <div id=" myid" class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.referenceNumber, new SelectList(Model.refNumDD, "referenceNumber", "referenceNumber"), "Choose reference")
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Screenshot of drop down that I have:**

[image]

**Screenshot of what I'm expecting:**

[image]

Is it possible to do this with the constraints that I have? I would appreciate your help. Thanks!

**Edited**

Here's the picture of my ADO.NET Data Source, I need ODBC Data Connection here which is not possible.

[image]

This is in Server Explorer:

[image]

Comment: You posted some code, but haven't described how it doesn't do what you want. What does it actually do, and how does that differ from your expectation? Does it execute without error? Does it run but give invalid results? Do you know how to filter the database query to only return relevant results? Your question initially makes it sound like you're having trouble figuring out the client side part, but then you post a bunch of server side code. So I'm unclear on what exactly you need help with.

Comment: Hi Mason, thanks for asking. I have issues only with client side. Since, the server is returning the data to drop down box, I had to post that code. I really have no idea how to approach with JQuery to get what I want as shown in second picture.

Comment: Of course you can connect to MySql. Use MySQL connector. Also, try using Entity Framework.

Comment: Phiter, I've updated my post with more pictures. Thanks.

Comment: @SreenathUmagandhi If you're having issues with the client side, then why did you list 3 different client side approaches? It just confuses your question. And when you reply to someone in the comments, use the @ syntax like I have done so that it notifies the person you're replying to.

Comment: As pointed out, your code as written already has a way to _obtain data_, so don't focus on that part. You should look into and try fulfilling your stated need of presenting that data to client side Javascript (instead of filling some control). At which point, your Javascript will handle "auto-complete". These are the rough tasks that you'll have to try out (too broad to go into tutorials).

Comment: @mason I listed them because I tried implementing them, it did nothing. Probably I could have gone wrong somewhere. But I tried doing this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/creating-autocomplete-textbox-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

Comment: @EdSF thank you, i'm not confused about obtaining data. Trying only for auto completion in context to my code.

Comment: Ok. You stated _"it is very straight forward to import that model directly using ADO.NET and write JQuery to make the drop down autocomplete"_ - strip everything about ADO.Net and you should be on your way(?).

Comment: You don't need to list other alternatives you tried, just one that you actually play to use will suffice. And if you're not confused about how to obtain the data, then don't show or talk about that part in your question. You're just confusing things. Take a step back and think about how an outsider is going to view your question when you put all that information in it. Focus on your actual problem, not extraneous details.